# Mobile - Codename - How can it be faster than native language?

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, mobile, native

#### Context :

Starting to write a mobile application for android and ios.

Looking at many alternatives. Can't stand the html5/webview thing. Most of the times it is sluggish. I tried many demo apps (phonegap/steroid..) and didn't feel at home. Not smooth enough.

More, some games are coming : so no way. I want a NATIVE development.

In itself, objective-c is not the problem. But if I can create the app with only one development, with a language that is easy to code in (java), that sounds nice.

#### Question :

[CodenameOne claims greater performance than objective-c via their java vm.](http://codenameone.blogspot.co.il/2012/12/codename-one-benchmarked-with-amazing.html)

Maybe they are using the C api, but this api is mostly obj-c now.

Do some devs or even the creators can tell me if I really don't have to code in the native iOS language (obj-c) and get better results through a java vm? **it seems odd to me.**

Comment: The Codename One iOS VM translates to C not Objective-C. The porting layer is in a mix of Objective-C and C but we try to reduce the amount of Objective-C for performance. In fact one of the biggest performance issues we have in our new VM is a piece of Objective-C code in the character encoding section... (FYI I wrote most of the code in our new VM)

Comment: @ShaiAlmog: ok so you are _doing_ what I had in _mind_ concerning the avoidance of obj-c. That is great Shai :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quote right from the page you have linked to:

> A small disclaimer is that the Objective-C benchmark is a bit heavy on the method/message calls which biases the benchmark in our favor. Method invocations in Codename One are naturally much faster than the equivalent Objective-C code due to the semantics of that language.

Doesn't that explain exactly what you have asked? Objective-C has an architecture due to which dynamic dispatch cannot be optimized, whereas Java's architecture allows for things like the monomorphic call site and even full method inlining. A benchmark which heavily focuses on exactly that aspect will skew the results in favor of the JVM, but the performance of actual apps is almost never dominated by method dispatch overhead.

Comment: Thanks. I read (and understood) that sentence :) But how could objective-c through apple's design not be as optimized ? in this case, why bother coding in native objective c at all if some other languages can beat the original-should-be optimized language on a platform ?

Comment: You choose to focus on wrong aspects: Apple did not see the necessity to optimize Objective-C in ways which are not relevant to application performance. You want to bother coding in the native language to get good performance from your *application*, not a single benchmark handpicked specifically because it exercises one narrow mechanism, the exact one which the alternative platform optimizes better.

Comment: So no magic : objective-c on ios and java on android, right ?

Comment: You can always try it out, but usually the non-native alternatives fail for one practical reason or another. Note that there is also Swift on iOS, and Apple clearly sees it as the way forward.

Comment: You are definitely right, but i need to support iOS 6 too.. :)

Comment: I agree that non-native fails for some cases but Codename One is designed to allow full access to native (FYI I am the co-founder of Codename One). Objective-C has several problems that slow it down including synchronous reference counting and slow message dispatching both of which are very slow. The former is still true for SWIFT I'm not sure about the latter. ARC improved the reference counting but the fact that you need reference counting to be threadsafe really slows stuff down. If a native app is coded in 100% C without using Objective-C features it will potentially be faster.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog If anything, I would want to avoid Objective-C's unsafe pointers and "automatic" reference counting (where just the *counting* is automatic and I still have to handcode around reference cycles and other RC concerns). Objective-C is a syntactic and semantic kludge of Smalltalk concepts on top of plain C. However, performance did not occur to me as something that needed fixing on iOS. Most application code isn't computationally intensive and all the intensive stuff goes on within the platform's library (which is, naturally, very much optimized).

Comment: I completely agree Marko. The goal of the benchmark mentioned above is mostly to show that our Java port is "competitive" with native in terms of performance. iOS apps are smooth because the libraries (core animation etc.) are ridiculously well optimized to the GPU.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know anything about CodenameOne, but about the general behavior of Java-VMs.
Typically java programms require more time to start up, due to intermediate java byte code having to be compiled before being executed. During execution the VM is however free to perform runtime optimizations, e.g. rearrangeing code blocks to make better use of CPU caches etc...
Since the VM can perform this step at runtime and thus has knowledge a static compiler doesnt have it can actually outpace even optimized C code at times.
An older example of real world benchmarks comparing C and Java can be found for [Jake2 (Quake2 ported to Java)](http://bytonic.de/html/benchmarks.html).

Comment: Syren, that benchmark shows nothing. We don't even have the compiler, the version, and the flags used. "march=native" and profile are very useful but not automatic, though.. No language fight here, but if java is consistently better than c, then fire the c coder, he doesn't know the language/optimizations enough.

Comment: I´m not looking for a language fight. I was referring to the part about "Do some devs or even the creators can tell me if I really don't have to code in the native iOS language (obj-c) and get better results through a java vm? **it seems odd to me**." It isnt necesarrily odd. A VM has information a static compiler doesnt have and **can** be faster.

Comment: We fully agree Syren :)

Comment: FYI one of the advantages Java has is fast memory allocation that is much faster than standard C malloc/free/calloc. The fact that the GC runs in the background allows better usage of multi-core chips especially with a proper concurrent VM. This also simplifies mulit-threaded code considerably. Big C apps can be optimized to a ridiculous degree (including custom malloc implementations) but that's not quite enough: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp09275/ One of the core problems in Java is that most Java implementations are optimized to servers not client code

Comment: @ShaiAlmog: thanks Shai. The difference in alloc speed is very *allocation* vs *recycling*. A well thought c code does not allocate that much but recycles, as java does. One of the slow java startup reason is precisely memory allocation.

Comment: One of the reasons for slow startup is that the default JVM loads 800 classes on startup and initializes a lot of objects (e.g. Strings). Our VM doesn't have classes but you get a lot of static initializer code (globals etc.) that get initialized which also requires some mutexes (to prevent concurrent initialization) then we also initialize the entire set of Strings used in the application (ideally this would be optimized in the future). Its not very noticeable on the iPhone 4 (not S) so we let this slide for now. There is always room for optimization here.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog: 100% agreed